# Javascript Object return failure

Tags: javascript, object, properties, return, closures

UPDATE: I've figured it out. Thank you to **eol** for getting me thinking about the promise. While the recommended script didn't get me there, the thinking did.

To get the object to pass properly, I needed to start with the object itself and restructure the code to support that end.

```
var barBuildX = function(csv, domainColumnName, rangeMin, rangeMax, paddingInner, paddingOuter) {
 var x = {
    rMin: rangeMin,
    rMax: rangeMax,
    padIn: paddingInner,
    padOut: paddingOuter,
    domain: (function() {
         var dom = [];
         d3.csv(csv).then(function(data) {
            data.forEach(function(d) {
            dom[dom.length] = d[domainColumnName];
            });
         })
         return dom;
      })(),
    };
    console.log(x);
    return x;
    };
 };
```

This is a fairly basic subroutine meant to populate an object with the fields necessary to satisfy a d3.js scaleBand() function. The first part of this script is working as expected - building an array of domain names based on the "domainColumnName" within the supplied CSV file. However, the second part, where we actually build the "x" object that will be returned, is not functioning properly - not writing to console or carrying back any of the data I'm attempting to pass to it. This is especially annoying seeing as it should just be setting property values and returning the object for use elsewhere... Any thoughts?

```
var barBuildX = function(csv, domainColumnName, rangeMin, rangeMax, paddingInner, PaddingOuter) {
  var dom = [];
  d3.csv(csv).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data); //this works
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      dom[dom.length] = d[domainColumnName];
    });
    console.log(dom); //this works
    var x = {
      domain: dom,
      rMin: rangeMin,
      rMax: rangeMax,
      padIn: paddingInner,
      padOut: paddingOuter
    };
    console.log(x); //this DOES NOT work
    return x; //Undefined... / Type Error
  });
};
```

There was a note of differences in variable spellings, that was unfortunately a mistake I made when copying over to this thread. There are no differences in variable spellings in the original source that isn't working.

The error message I'm getting in the Chrome console is: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'domain' of undefined"

So, the return object is coming in as undefined...

Comment: `paddingOuter` is spelled differently to the argument

Comment: This looks like you are running into a [duplicate of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), except that the values should be defined at the point you say they are not. "this DOES NOT work" and "Undefined... / Type Error" are not clear problem statements. You should quote error messages exactly, and state where you are reading them from.

Comment: "paddingOuter is spelled differently to the argument" — Which means you should get a *reference error* two lines before you say you have any error.

Comment: As I'm working on an offline system, I manually re-entered the code here. The paddingOuter spelling is the same in the original source code...

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] which actually demonstrates your problem. Ideally as a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). There's an **Edit** link under the question.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I've figured out the problem and updated the thread to reflect the working script.

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning the promise from within your function, which is why you'll get `undefined` as a return value. Do something like this:

```
var barBuildX = function(csv, domainColumnName, rangeMin, rangeMax, paddingInner, PaddingOuter) {
  var dom = [];
  return d3.csv(csv).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data); //this works
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      dom[dom.length] = d[domainColumnName];
    });
    console.log(dom); //this works
    var x = {
      domain: dom,
      rMin: rangeMin,
      rMax: rangeMax,
      padIn: paddingInner,
      padOut: paddingOuter
    };
    console.log(x); //this DOES NOT work
    return x; //Undefined... / Type Error
  });
};

// how to invoke the function:
barBuildX(...).then(x => {
   console.log(x);
});
```